# Separating a tuple and saving it to a file

Tags: python, file, tuples

I currently have this code:

```
from collections import  OrderedDict
a = [(1), (7), (3), (1)]
b = [(2), (4), (7), (4)]
c = [(8), (1), (3), (3)]
d = (list(OrderedDict((sub[0], sub) for sub in sorted(zip(a, b, c))).values()))
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4, 3), (3, 7, 3), (7, 4, 1)]
```

I am currently trying to save to 3 files.
`D://a.txt`, `D://b.txt` and `D://c.txt`

In `D://a.txt` I want to save:

```
1
3
7
```

In `D://b.txt` I want to save:

```
4
7
4
```

And in `D://c.txt` I want to save:

```
3
3
1
```

I know how to save it:

```
with open("D:\\a.txt", "a") as myfile1:
   myfile1.write(num1)
   myfile1.write("\n")
```

Or with b.txt:

```
with open("D:\\b.txt", "a") as myfile2:
   myfile2.write(num2)
   myfile2.write("\n")
```

with num1 and num2 in this case to be used like:

```
for num1 in a:
   myfile1.write(num1)
   myfile1.write("\n")
```

My objective is to save the numbers in `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` without any `(` `)` `[` `]` `,`

Comment: Please describe the criterion on which the output numbers should be selected more detailed since I do not get any hint about that.

Comment: @albert it's just index 0 goes to a index 1 goes to b and index 2 goes to c

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d
[(1, 4, 3), (3, 7, 3), (7, 4, 1)]
>>> with open('a.txt','w') as fa, open('b.txt','w') as fb, open('c.txt','w') as fc:
...     for a,b,c in d:
...         fa.write(str(a) + '\n')
...         fb.write(str(b) + '\n')
...         fc.write(str(c) + '\n')
...         
>>> !cat a.txt
1
3
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
letters = ("a", "b", "c")
for i, nums in enumerate(zip(d)):
    with open("D:\\{}.txt".format(letters[i]), "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("\n".join(str(num) for num in nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of tuples as well as the number of entries in each tuple in `d` can vary:

```
for i, nums in enumerate(zip(*d)):
    fname = '/tmp/%s.txt' % chr(ord('a') + i)
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join('%s' % n for n in nums))
```

This way you get exactly what you want:

```
!cat /tmp/a.txt
1
3
7
!cat /tmp/b.txt
4
7
4
!cat /tmp/c.txt
3
3
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start assuming that the code that gets the list of tuples works and does not need any adjusting.

since d is a list of tuples, I'm going to assign 3 variables, one to each tuple to make things simpler for now.

```
a = d[0] #(1,4,3)
b = d[1] #(3,7,3)
c = d[2] #(7,4,1)
```

Now, it's time to loop through them, and assign the values to the files.

```
for x in a:
    with open("D:\\a.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(x)
        file.write("\n")

for y in b:
    with open("D:\\b.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(y)
        file.write("\n")

for z in c:
    with open("D:\\c.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(z)
        file.write("\n")
```

Your output should be free of any type of brackets or parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not confident that you're doing what you are trying to do, your definition of `d` could be rewritten in a more simple fashion, and then `e` could be created to pair up the entries in each resultant tuple.

```
a = [(1), (7), (3), (1)]
b = [(2), (4), (7), (4)]
c = [(8), (1), (3), (3)]
d = sorted(zip(a, b, c))[1:] # [(1, 4, 3), (3, 7, 3), (7, 4, 1)]
e = list(zip(*d)) # [(1, 3, 7), (4, 7, 4), (3, 3, 1)]
```

Then, you could write to each file as:

```
for name, values in zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], e):
    with open('D:\\{}.txt'.format(name), 'w') as myfile:
        myfile.write('\n'.join(map(str,values))
```